# How can I access Data in Google Storage via Presto?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, presto

I have requirement for the data lake where depending on the use case applications are using different type of storage. I have MySQL, Hive, Google Cloud Storage. I am using Presto as query engine. I want make it one stop solution where people can access data any type of the data storage? I have configured MySQL Connector & Hive Connector are working good. I tried to use TPCH connector to connect with Google Cloud Storage.

Is it right approach? Am I in correct direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage connector for Presto does not exist as far as I know.
You may consider building one and contributing back to the open source.
Alternatively feel free to contact Starburst Data (www.starburstdata.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answers here are out of date since this link shows a GCS connector is available now : https://docs.starburst.io/latest/connector/hive-gcs-tutorial.html

Comment: Hey Simon, can you maybe edit your answer to elaborate a bit more, what can be found behind the link, so people can get the information right away and only follow the link for further information and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

No, TPCH connector (https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/connector/tpch.html) is not meant to connect to any real storage engine. Instead it generates at runtime data for tables needed to the TPC-H benchmark. Its main use is to test ANSI SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a [Minio Server](https://github.com/minio/minio) and use [Hive Connector(S3)](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html)

Comment: Also it looks like GCS support was released in [302 version](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/release/release-302.html)